# Idiomatic way to get a hold of the input value/context of the operation that caused an exception in Spring?

Tags: spring-boot, project-reactor

I'm using Spring and the operators from project reactor (Mono, Flux etc) and my question is concerning error handling. Let's say I have this code:

```
val fluxOfNames : Flux<String> = ..
fluxOfNames.flatMap { name ->
    externalResource.fetchInfo(name)    
}.doOnError { throwable ->
    // TODO How can I get the "name" that failed?
    println("$name failed due to ${throwable.message")
}. ..
```

I'd like to print the `name` that failed but it's not in scope in the lambda function passed to `doOnError` afaik. I could probably wrap the call to `externalResource.fetchInfo(name)` in a custom exception containing the value of the `name` parameter but it quickly becomes ugly if I have to do this all over the place.

Is there a way for me to get a hold of the value of `name` in the `doOnError` lambda expression when the `throwable` doesn't contain this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is you're making an assumption that the error processed by `doOnError` (or any `onError*` operator for that matter) comes from the operator immediately above it. But really, it can come from further up the chain. Or it can come up during a terminal signal, thus not associated with a value at all...

In your case fortunately, you are using `flatMap`. Simply put the `doOnError` *inside* the flatMap so that it only captures errors from the `externalResource.fetchInfo`. That way the `name` is still in scope and you can use it in the error message.